# Datatable did not show dynamic data which i fetch from database in react js

Tags: reactjs, datatables, mdbreact

I have integrated datatable in my react js web app.

It works with sample data as i have mentioned in the code pagelist

> I have tried to make it component but did not get the result. I am new
>   in react and did not able to clue to further progress.

Here the list of my import packages

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Switch,Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { MDBDataTable} from 'mdbreact';
```

// The below call get the data as i have confirmed in the console log

```
axios.get('/api/pagelist').then(response => {

    var pagelist = JSON.stringify(response.data);
    console.log(pagelist);

});
```

//Sample test data which works with the example

```
var pagelist = [{
    name: 'Tiger Nixon',
    position: 'System Architect',
    office: 'Edinburgh',
    age: '61',
    date: '2011/04/25',
    salary: '$12320'
},
{
    name: 'Gavin Joyce',
    position: 'Developer',
    office: 'Edinburgh',
    age: '42',
    date: '2010/12/22',
    salary: '$92'
},
{
    name: 'Jennifer Chang',
    position: 'Regional Director',
    office: 'Singapore',
    age: '28',
    date: '2010/11/14',
    salary: '$357'
},
{
    name: 'Donna Snider',
    position: 'Customer Support',
    office: 'New York',
    age: '27',
    date: '2011/01/25',
    salary: '$112'
}
];
```

// Just copy the function and change columns as guided by the documentation

```
const DatatablePage = () => {
    const data = {
        columns: [{
            label: 'ID',
            field: 'id',
            sort: 'asc',
            width: 60
            },
            {
                label: 'Name',
                field: 'name',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 150
            },

            {
                label: 'Title',
                field: 'title',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 150
            },
            {
                label: 'Slug',
                field: 'slug',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 100
            },
            {
                label: 'Content',
                field: 'content',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 250
            },
            {
                label: 'Created',
                field: 'created_at',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 100
            }
        ],
        rows: pagelist
    };
    return (

        <MDBDataTable striped bordered hover data = {data}/>
    );
}
```

//Finally exported it

```
export default DatatablePage;
```

Comment: The sample data is from https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/datatables/, can you provide what your actual data looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a scoping issue to me.  The data variable you're storing the page data in is scoped to the axios callback.  Once the code leaves that callback, your data is no longer accessible.

```
axios.get('/api/pagelist').then(response => {

    // pageList scoped locally.  not accessible outside.  this is why the
    // console.log works, but there's no data in the table.
    var pagelist = JSON.stringify(response.data);  
    console.log(pagelist);

});
```

Assuming you're using a component, I suggest adding a constructor and that you create a state property. E.g.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {pageList: []} ;

}
```

You need to then update this in the axios.get....

```
axios.get('/api/pagelist').then(response => {

    // The below line may not be exactly correct.  May need to review.
    this.setState({pagelist: JSON.stringify(response.data)}, console.log("state updated));

});
```

Finally, the rows assignment in the datatables method needs to be

```
rows: this.state.pagelist
```